# How to restrict user from from multiple enter key press

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a submit button . I want to show a warning message to users for that I have called the following function. I'm calling this method from on client click event. After hitting submit button I am opening Money Receipt using crystal report. But how can I restrict users from multiple enter key press. I am getting multiple submission. I am working on web form (.net framework 2.0.).

```
 function WarningMessage()
 {
  confirm("Are you sure?\nNo alteration will be allowed after Payment.");
 }
```

Comment: You can set a flag `processing` and call server only if this flag is set to false. Once called, set it to true and once you get response, you can reset it to false.

Comment: Can you add the HTML where you call the function. You've a submission when cancel is pressed ?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" TabIndex="21" SkinID="btnNormal"
                                    OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" OnClientClick="return WarningMessage(); " />

Comment: Rajesh Ji can you explain your idea of flag processing in more details. I mean by code.